# Trying to install oracle on Scientific Linux release 6.2

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle11g, yum

We are trying to install Oracle11g on Scientific Linux release 6.2 using yum and we are getting a error

This is the command:

```
yum install oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall
```

This is the output error:

```
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
Retrieving key from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle


GPG key retrieval failed: [Errno 14] Could not open/read file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
```

Answer (score 6):

```
wget https://public-yum.oracle.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle-ol6 -O /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
```

Run the above command. I just now did the same.

[Edit]
Or go to the link http://public-yum.oracle.com/ to scroll down to get the link compatible to your OS.

Answer (score 2):

try this

wget --no-check-certificate  https://public-yum.oracle.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle-ol6 -O /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle

Comment: Using `--no-check-certificate` is a really bad, bad practice. Shall never be recommended, at least without warning.

Comment: I agree 100% with kgadek -- there's no good reason to have wget ignore a certificate's validity.  It's also a shame that Oracle doesn't include instructions for getting and installing their key.  They should provide checksums at the very least, but since they don't you definitely want wget to check the certificate to make sure you're downloading the key from an Oracle server.

Answer (score 0):

**check whether below package install**
1) rpm -q epel-release

package epel-release is not installed

**then install it**

**2) yum install package epel-release***

```
> 3) wget https://public-yum.oracle.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle-ol7 -O /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle --no-check-certificate

4)wget https://public-yum.oracle.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle-ol7 -O /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle --no-check-certificate
```